# Form validation not working due to absent of form fields

Tags: javascript

I have a form with validators. JS for form validation are as under:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Generate a simple captcha
  function randomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  };
  $('#captchaOperation').html([randomNumber(1, 100), '+', randomNumber(1, 200), '='].join(' '));

  $('#defaultForm').bootstrapValidator({
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    fields: {
      field1: {
        message: 'The field is not valid',
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'The field is required and can\'t be empty'
          },
          stringLength: {
            min: 1,
            max: 30,
            message: 'The field must be more than 1 and less than 30 characters long'
          },
          regexp: {
            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
            message: 'The field can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
          }

        }
      },
      field2: {
        message: 'The field is not valid',
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'The field is required and can\'t be empty'
          },
          stringLength: {
            min: 1,
            max: 30,
            message: 'The field must be more than 1 and less than 30 characters long'
          },
          regexp: {
            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
            message: 'The field can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
          }

        }
      },
      field3: {
        message: 'The field is not valid',
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'The field is required and can\'t be empty'
          },
          stringLength: {
            min: 1,
            max: 30,
            message: 'The field must be more than 1 and less than 30 characters long'
          },
          regexp: {
            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
            message: 'The field can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
          }

        }
      },
      field4: {
        message: 'The field is not valid',
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'The field is required and can\'t be empty'
          },
          stringLength: {
            min: 1,
            max: 30,
            message: 'The field must be more than 1 and less than 30 characters long'
          },
          regexp: {
            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
            message: 'The field can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
          }

        }
      },
      field5: {
        message: 'The field is not valid',
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'The field is required and can\'t be empty'
          },
          stringLength: {
            min: 1,
            max: 30,
            message: 'The field must be more than 1 and less than 30 characters long'
          },
          regexp: {
            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
            message: 'The field can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
          }

        }
      },



      captcha: {
        validators: {
          callback: {
            message: 'Wrong answer',
            callback: function(value, validator) {
              var items = $('#captchaOperation').html().split(' '),
                sum = parseInt(items[0]) + parseInt(items[2]);
              return value == sum;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/master/src/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>

<!-- form: -->
<form id="defaultForm" method="post" action="exam.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">
      <?php echo "$field1";?>
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field1" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">
      <?php echo "$field2";?>
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field2" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">
      <?php echo "$field3";?>
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field3" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">
      <?php echo "$field4";?>
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field4" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">
      <?php echo "$field5";?>
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field5" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" id="captchaOperation"></label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Some form fields including labels are removed on load through js. As a result validators are available but the respective fields are not available and thus form validator is not working. Will you please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Note that the bootstrap validator plugin is "no longer supported" https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator

Comment: But otherwise it is working fine;

Comment: Yes, but if you encounter bugs, they will not be fixed;  if you have the option, it's usually better to use plugins that have a lot of eyes on them and are maintained, that way when you run into a bug, there is a community out there to help fix it.

Comment: Are the fields in question always removed? Would it be possible to hide them instead?

Comment: The source for bootstrapValidator says that it doesn't validate hidden, not visible, or disabled fields. If hiding works, that might be a cheap and easy win. Otherwise, it looks like BV exposes a removeField() function that takes one param - the field name or field element (jquery object). Looks promising. Your fiddle isn't really doing much for me, which makes it hard to check.